# Finding the lowest value between dates for the same ID on excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, range

Here is what I wanna do:

I want column Q to have the lowest Dificulty value as possible for the same Institute, considering the last day of the month that had an exercise.

What I need to do: take the last day of that month for each institute (7/31/14 in this case), find the lowest value that appeared in that day and put it in all the lines for that specific Institute in column Q

Note: the data NEED to be ordered like in the pic, you cant sort it in other ways. Is there a way to do it via formula (not vba or anything)?

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aICcP.png)

Comment: Why people down voting the post? Can any one explain reason of down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you. Press 1Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after entering following formula as it is an array formula.

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$19=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$19=B2,$A$2:$A$19)),IF($B$2:$B$19=B2,$D$2:$D$19)))
```

[image]